# Design Tweak: The "know someone" banner is too dark and visually prominent

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

More aesthetic than anything.

The banner under a question which states: "Know someone who can answer? Share a link to this question via email, Google+, Twitter, or Facebook." is currently a dark background with reversed text.

This is *exceptionally* visually prominent in the design. I feel a lighter, less obtrusive color may serve this banner area a bit better.

The dark background works *very* well at the bottom of the page, it's this mid-page banner which just yanks your eye to it in a drastic fashion.

For what it's worth, I think perhaps the teal background used for the "community Bulletin" on the right side may be a better background color for this banner area - still prominent, but not as visually striking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree, I've changed the design to something lighter. It doesn't need to be visually prominent. It'll be live after our next production build.